# How can I apply a function call to an alias?

Tags: python, yaml, pyyaml

My target is to allow an easy way to “filter” previously defined nodes. Consider this fictional YAML file:

```
%YAML 1.1
---
- fruit: &fruitref { type: banana, color: yellow }
- another_fruit: !rotten *fruitref
```

What do I need to define in either the YAML file or the Python code that parses this file in order to call a custom function with `*fruitref` (i.e. the previously defined object, in this case a map) as argument and get the return value? The target is as simple and terse a syntax for “filtering” a previously defined value (map, sequence, whatever).

### Note

It seems to me that the construct `!`*tag* `*`*alias* is invalid YAML, because of the error:

```
expected <block end>, but found '<alias>'
  in "/tmp/test.yaml", line 4, column 21
```

which most possibly implies that I won't be able to achieve the required syntax, but I do care about terseness (or rather, the target users will).

### Routes taken

#### YAML: `!!python/object/apply:__main__.rotten [*fruitref]`

It works but it is too verbose for the intended use; and there is no need for multiple arguments, the use case is **ALWAYS** a filter for an alias (a previously defined map/sequence/object).

#### YAML: `%TAG !f! !!python/object/apply:__main__.`

Perhaps `!f!rotten [*fruitref]` would be acceptable, but I can't find how to make use of the `%TAG` directive.
EDIT: I discovered that the `!!` doesn't work for PyYAML 3.10, it has to be the complete URL like this: `%TAG !f! %TAG !f! tag:yaml.org,2002:python/object/apply:__main__.`

#### Python: `yaml.add_constructor`

I already use `add_constructor` for “casting” maps to specific instances of my classes; the caveat is that *tag alias* seems to be invalid YAML.

### Best so far

`add_constructor('!rotten', filter_rotten)` in Python and `!rotten [*fruitref]` in YAML seem to work, but I'm wondering how to omit the square brackets if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that it is not possible to apply a tag to an already tagged reference, so:

```
!tag *reference
```

is not acceptable. The best possible solution is to enclose the reference to square brackets (create a sequence) and make the tag to be either a function call or a special constructor expecting a sequence of one object, so the tersest syntax available is:

```
!prefix!suffix [*reference]
```

or

```
!tag [*reference]
```

Comment: I'm selecting my own answer for the time being.

Comment: I have the same problem, where I try to apply a custom tag `!rand` to an alias (a `sequence` alias) - when I put the alias in brackets it gets resolved to an empty list.


https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53776602/how-to-make-a-custom-yaml-tag-work-with-a-sequence-alias-in-pyyaml/53779426