# How to make a custom YAML tag work with a sequence alias in pyyaml

Tags: python, tags, yaml, pyyaml

I’ve got a yaml file with aliases like this:

```
vars:
  users: &users ['user1', 'user2', 'user3', 'user4']

refs:
  users: *users
  user: !rand ['user1', 'user2', 'user3', 'user4']
```

`!rand` is a custom tag that calls python’s `random.choice` on a yaml sequence.

I’m using the following implementation of the `!rand` tag:

```
import random
import yaml

def load_yaml(file):
    def rand_constructor(loader, node):
        value = loader.construct_sequence(node)
        return random.choice(value)

    yaml.add_constructor('!rand', rand_constructor)

    with open(file) as f:
        return yaml.load(f)
```

It works as expected, and `user` gets a random value from `users`.
Now, when I use `!rand` with the alias `*users` it stops working:

```
vars:
  users: &users ['user1', 'user2', 'user3', 'user4']

refs:
  users: *users
  user: !rand *users
```

The error is:

```
File ../python3.6/site-packages/yaml/parser.py", line 439, in parse_block_mapping_key
    "expected <block end>, but found %r" % token.id, token.start_mark)
yaml.parser.ParserError: while parsing a block mapping
  in "/temp/config.yml", line 5, column 3
expected <block end>, but found '<alias>'
  in "/temp/config.yml", line 6, column 18
```

How do I make it work with sequence aliases?

Answer (score 2):

In YAML, tags are designed to define content type. They are *not* designed to process content.

For this reason, you cannot tag an alias, since an alias is just a reference to content which has already been tagged at the location where it's defined. In your case, your sequence will get the `!!seq` tag according to the [YAML core schema](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2804923). YAML does not provide the ability to re-tag it.

Having said that, you can of course do a workaround: Wrap the `!rand` parameter in a sequence:

```
vars:
  users: &users ['user1', 'user2', 'user3', 'user4']

refs:
  users: *users
  user: !rand [*users]
```

You then just need to change your code to:

```
import random
import yaml

def load_yaml(file):
    def rand_constructor(loader, node):
        value = loader.construct_sequence(node)
        return random.choice(value[0])

    yaml.add_constructor('!rand', rand_constructor)

    with open(file) as f:
        return yaml.load(f)
```

But be aware that a direct call to `!rand` then looks like this:

```
vars:
  users: &users ['user1', 'user2', 'user3', 'user4']

refs:
  users: *users
  user: !rand [['user1', 'user2', 'user3', 'user4']]
```

See it like the outer sequence being the parameter list of the function `!rand` (which takes one parameter) and the inner sequence being that parameter.

Comment: with the changes you suggested, when I change it to `user2: !rand [*users]` the resulting `value` gets set to an empty list `[[]]`
And the traceback says:
"IndexError: Cannot choose from an empty sequence"

Comment: Sorry, I did not test this. May need some tweaking; could also be that aliases are being resolved too late for it to work. I just assumed this works based on other YAML loading libs I know.

Answer (score 2):

You can also make your list callable and call it each time you need random user:

```
YAML = """
user: &users !rand 
    - user1
    - user2
    - user3
    - user4
"""

import random
import yaml
from collections.abc import Sequence

class RandomizableList(Sequence):
    def __init__(self, items):
        self.items = items
    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.items)
    def __getitem__(self, value):
        return self.items[value]
    def __call__(self):
        return random.choice(self.items)
    def __repr__(self):
        return repr(self.items)

def rand_constructor(loader, node):
    return RandomizableList(loader.construct_sequence(node))

yaml.add_constructor('!rand', rand_constructor)
result = yaml.load(YAML)
for i in range(4):
    print(result['user']())
print(result['user'])
```